# Sending non-text files from machine to another using C++

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp

I'm trying to build an application which allows a user to transfer files/directories from its computer to another computer when he wants in LAN ~ TCP/IP without any intervention of the receiver computer's user.

To deal this, I think Sockets would be the best alternative. Because if I use FTP and let the receiver's computer's FTP port open continually that would be a vulnerability.

Is the use of Sockets the best choise?

If yes, how to send directories and non-text files throw sockets?

Comment: FTP uses sockets too. So if you reinvent something similar to FTP you have not changed the vulnerability of an open port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to security, it's really a matter of "whatever you do, it will only be as safe as the keeping of the password/credentials needed to log in". Using FTPS or SSH protocols will encrypt the traffic between the machines, ensuring that nobody outside can "see" what the files are (or passwords, etc). SSH also has features to identify if the remote machine suddenly changes, so you can identify if somebody has introduced a "man in the middle" attack (that is, pretending to be your actual machine you are sending to)

As for sending non-text files, it shouldn't really be any different than sending text-files in all cases I'm aware of. Of coruse, if you use FTP, you need to set the protocol to "binary mode" before sending binary files, as some systems will otherwise "modify" the content (e.g. translating CR, LF and CRLF sequences to match the target - and a JPG image will certainly look quite weird when all the bytes with value 0x0A has been replaced with 0x0D 0x0A in the file...).

Of course, you could also set up a web-server with suitable software on the receiving machine and use HTTP/HTTPS protocol to upload files - with or without password protection (and in HTTPS, the password is safe as long as nobody "outside group of trust" has access to the actual sending/receiving machine, as the traffic is encrypted).

There are literally several hundred other solutions. Without understanding MUCH more about exactly what problem you are trying to solve, it's hard to make very concrete solutions.

Comment: So the use of FTP is better than raw sockets?

Comment: Define "better"... Of course, if you want to "hide" yourself, not using a standard protocol will make it harder for someone to find your traffic. But it's more work, and if someone really wants to know what's going on, wireshark or something like that will still see the traffic. Encryption will make it "hard" to read tho'.

Comment: Then, Do I need to develop two applications? One which listens the ftp port and the other which sends directories? But, how do I identify the trafic sent by the sender app?

Comment: Most OS's have a supported FTP-server that you can use. How to detect files? And you can either use cURL or similar library to send the files - or even use command-line tools. Check if there are "new files" in a particular directory, perhaps? There are calls for notifications on "new files in directory" for both Linux and Windows. But like I said in the answer, without actually understanding what you are trying to do, it's hard to give good answers - basically, you are asking "How do I best do X?" but you are not telling us exactly what the "big picture" is.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some sort of server on the receiving machine as there is not normally any process listening and writing what it receives into the filesystem. Have a practice with netcat (also known as nc) before you write too much code. [See here.](http://tapasmishra.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/how-to-copy-large-files-without-scp-or-rsync/)